# RSocket not working when secured with TLS - server java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException - client java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: reactor-netty, rsocket, rsocket-java

**UPDATE** I've uploaded a [sample project to Github](https://github.com/codependent/rsocket-tls/) where you can reproduce the problem. Check the instructions in the readme.

I have an RSocket Server that is available for request streams, generating a Flux with n random numbers:

```
class RequestStreamRSocketServer

@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
fun main() {

    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    RSocketFactory.receive()
        .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.DEFAULT)
        .acceptor { setup, sendingSocket ->
            Mono.just(
                object : AbstractRSocket() {
                    override fun requestStream(payload: Payload): Flux<Payload> {
                        val randomNumberGenerator = Random(1234)
                        val numbers = payload.dataUtf8.toInt()
                        println("Generating $numbers random numbers")
                        return IntRange(1, numbers)
                            .map { DefaultPayload.create(randomNumberGenerator.nextUInt().toString().toByteArray()) }
                            .toList().toFlux()
                    }
                })
        }
        .transport(
            TcpServerTransport.create(TcpServer.create().port(7878))
        )
        .start()
        .block()

    latch.await()
}
```

I've also created a client that connects to the RSocket and requests 10 random numbers:

```
class RequestStreamRSocketClient

@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
fun main() {

    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    val path = RequestStreamRSocketClient::class.java.getResource("truststore.jks").path
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path)
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "123456")


    val client = RSocketFactory.connect()
        .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.DEFAULT)
        .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(TcpClient.create().port(7878)))
        .start()
        .block()

    client.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create("10"))
        .map { it.dataUtf8 }
        //.onErrorReturn("error")
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .doOnComplete { latch.countDown() }
        .doOnError { it.printStackTrace() }
        .subscribe()

    latch.await()
}
```

This runs perfectly.

**Server logs:**

```
Generating 10 random numbers
```

**Client logs:**

```
345130239
2958210271
3979283303
4254072378
4206518657
1432197826
3787126071
2479634382
4147073748
3864383859

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However I would like to use TLS in the RSocket communication so I created a certificate.pem/key.pem for the server and configured it:

```
.transport(
    TcpServerTransport.create(TcpServer.create().port(7878).secure {
        it.sslContext(
            SslContextBuilder.forServer(
                File(RequestStreamRSocketServer::class.java.getResource("certificate.pem").toURI()),
                File(RequestStreamRSocketServer::class.java.getResource("key.pem").toURI())
            )
        )
    })
)
```

On the client side, I created a truststore.jks, imported the certificate.pem and configured the client to use a secure communication:

```
    val path = RequestStreamRSocketClient::class.java.getResource("truststore.jks").path
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path)
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "123456")
    ...

        .transport(TcpClientTransport.create(TcpClient.create().port(7878).secure {
            it.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient())
        }))
```

After starting the server I launch the client. The server's acceptor-request stream is called (printing `Generating 10 random numbers`) but immediately fails:

```
Generating 10 random numbers
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: promise already done: DefaultChannelPromise@4f230679(failure: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.isNotValidPromise(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:891)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:773)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:701)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.finishWrap(SslHandler.java:899)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:885)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:797)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:778)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner$AsyncFlush.run(MonoSendMany.java:621)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

On the client side there's a closed channel exception:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.terminate(RSocketRequester.java:476)
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.lambda$new$0(RSocketRequester.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.runFinally(FluxDoFinally.java:156)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor$NextInner.onComplete(MonoProcessor.java:518)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:308)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onComplete(MonoProcessor.java:265)
    at io.rsocket.internal.BaseDuplexConnection.dispose(BaseDuplexConnection.java:23)
    at io.rsocket.transport.netty.TcpDuplexConnection.lambda$new$0(TcpDuplexConnection.java:61)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:472)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:413)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:538)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:527)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:98)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:1156)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:734)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:605)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:621)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:605)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:467)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1092)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:268)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1388)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:174)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I fix it to work with TLS?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed after upgrade to RC7 and minor refactor:

Server:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    RSocketServer.create()
        .payloadDecoder(PayloadDecoder.DEFAULT)
        .acceptor { setup, sendingSocket ->
            Mono.just(
                object : AbstractRSocket() {
                    override fun requestStream(payload: Payload): Flux<Payload> {
                        val randomNumberGenerator = Random(1234)
                        val numbers = payload.dataUtf8.toInt()
                        println("Generating $numbers random numbers")
                        return IntRange(1, numbers)
                            .map { DefaultPayload.create(randomNumberGenerator.nextUInt().toString().toByteArray()) }
                            .toList().toFlux()
                    }
                })
        }.bind(
            TcpServerTransport.create(TcpServer.create().port(7878)
                .secure {
                    it.sslContext(
                        SslContextBuilder.forServer(
                            File(RequestStreamRSocketServer::class.java.getResource("certificate.pem").toURI()),
                            File(RequestStreamRSocketServer::class.java.getResource("key.pem").toURI())
                        )
                    )
                })
        )
        .block()

    latch.await()
```

Client:

```
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    val client = RSocketConnector.connectWith(
        TcpClientTransport.create(TcpClient.create().port(7878)
            .secure {
                it.sslContext(
                    SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(
                        File(
                            RequestStreamRSocketClient::class.java.getResource(
                                "certificate.pem"
                            ).path
                        )
                    )
                )
            })
    ).block()!!

    client.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create("10"))
        .map { it.dataUtf8 }
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .doOnComplete { latch.countDown() }
        .doOnError { it.printStackTrace() }
        .subscribe()

    latch.await()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the Client Cert as below:

```
.transport(() -> {
                            TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create().host("localhost").port(7878);
                            return TcpClientTransport.create(keyCertChainFile != null ?
                                    tcpClient.secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec
                                        .sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager("client-cert.pem", "client-key.pem")
                                        .trustManager(new File("cacert.pem")))) :
                                    tcpClient);
                        }
```

Comment: I’m looking for a way to solve it only with server authentication. It’ll be a service exposed to multiple different clients that won’t have to present their own certificates

Comment: I experience that exception when there is Null Pointer in Server or any other illegal argument. I would say that this might be a transformed exception at client. Can you please check and post if there is any exception at server? Try using this at server end: `.clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)`

Comment: Hi Karthik, I appreciate your suggestions. I haven't seen other kind of exception. Check the updated question, I've uploaded a sample project to Github where you can see the problem.